# Is there a way to detect screen size with Apache Freemarker (ftl) templates?

Tags: apache, templates, freemarker, responsive, screen-size

Is there a way to detect screen width with just Freemarker templates? I'm looking for something along the lines of the following:

```
<#if screenwidth > 980px >
  <#include "big_banner.ftl">
<#else>
  <#include "small_banner.ftl">
</#if>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's out of the scope of FreeMarker. You could add a `screenWidth` to the data-model, but FreeMarker doesn't tell how to calculate the value of that.